# Loading nested objects without using INCLUDE + Oracle 11.2.0.1.0 does not support APPLY

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, linq

I need an elegant solution to load all the items related to my main entity.
Let's say I have `users` and `users` have `roles` but `roles` have `groups` and `currency` and I need to load them all.

I was trying:

```
var users = db.Users
              .Include("Roles")
              .Include("Roles.Group")
              .Include("Roles.Currency")
              .Where(x => x.Status == "1")
              .ToList();
```

But then I got `Oracle 11.2.0.1.0 does not support APPLY`

So I came with an horrible solution (it works, but honestly, I don't like it):

```
var users = db.Users
             .Include("Roles")
             .Where(x => x.Status == "1")
             .ToList();

// Then I load all nested objects in memory so I can reference them later.
foreach (var user in users)
{
    user.Roles.Currency = user.Roles.Currency;
    user.Roles.Group = user.Roles.Group;
    user.Roles.Users = usuario.Roles.Users;
}
```

And if I have another collection inside the main object, `user.Roles.Group` for example, I have to use another `foreach`.

Any suggestions on how can I make this code look and perform better?